# Wie ist zu erklären, dass das Wort »App« von manchen als sächliches Nomen verwendet wird?

Tags: gender

Bisher kannte ich das Wort »App« nur als feminines Wort:

> Dafür gibt es eine App.

Was ja auch ganz natürlich ist, weil »die App« die Kurzform von »die Applikation«, was wiederum ein Fremdwort für »die Anwendung« ist.

Aber heute bin ich im Internet auf das Foto eines Plakat eines Mineralölkonzerns gestoßen, worauf groß zu lesen ist:

> **KOSTENLOSES APP**
>   Kostenloses Smartphone-App herunterladen unter ...

Hier wird das Substantiv »App« verwendet, als wäre es ein sächliches Wort. Aber was ich zunächst für einen Fehler hielt, scheint zumindest so weit verbreitet zu sein, dass die sächliche Form auch bei [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/App) angezeigt wird. Sogar der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/App) hat an der sächlichen Version nichts auszusetzen.

Ich kann aber nicht nachvollziehen, wie es dazu gekommen ist, dass manche dieses Wort als sächlich betrachten. Was könnte der Grund dafür sein?

Comment: Immerhin steht beim Duden noch "selten" dran. Und laut Quellenangabe hat Wiki dort abgeschrieben - aber das "selten" leider nicht übernommen.

Comment: "das Programm"?

Comment: Ich habe die Verwendung im Neutrum noch nirgendwo gesehen, und sehe auch keinerlei Anlass für ein Neutrum - kann als Begründung also nur tiefgründige Verwirrung angeben. Kann ja mal vorkommen.

Comment: Hier ein Link zum [Bild von dem Plakat](https://scontent-vie1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/22046963_483044415385884_1734238437799314553_n.jpg?oh=ce6ce25616cb24e4af20bd8bd5478c30&oe=5A87C185). Es wurde angeblich gestern in der Nähe von Hörselberg-Hainich in Thüringen fotografiert.

Comment: Esso scheint sich selbst nicht so ganz sicher zu sein: http://corporate.exxonmobil.de/de-de/unternehmen/multimedia/apps/esso-app (feminin), https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/esso-fuel-finder/id521914331?mt=8 (feminin und Neutrum auf einer Seite, die App selbst scheint sich laut Screenshot für feminin zu halten). Ich gehe davon aus, dass es sich jedesmal um das gleiche Ding handelt.

Comment: Ein weiteres Beispiel aus der Gamerwelt: Der Mod -> Die Modifikation.

Answer (score 4):

Ich würde vermuten, dass bei der Entlehnung von IT-Wörtern aus dem Englischen in einigen Regionen, darunter etwa die Schweiz (wo wir «das App» sagen), eine relative Vorliebe für das Neutrum besteht, z.B. das SMS, das E-Mail, das Flash-Drive, das Setup, das Helpdesk.

Comment: *Das SMS, das E-Mail, das Flash-Drive* und *das Setup* sind auch in Österreich üblich. Ich wusste gar nicht, dass Flash-Drive und Setup auch andere Artikel haben können. (Welche eigentlich? *Die Setup* kommt mir genau so falsch vor wie *der Setup*. Dasselbe gilt für *die/der Flash-Drive*.) Lediglich der Helpdesk ist in Österreich männlich. Aber nach diesem Argument müsste die App auch in Österreich sächlich sein, was nicht der Fall ist. Auf »das App« bin ich ja auf einem Foto aus Thüringen gestoßen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, bei uns (Ostdeutschland): der Setup und der Drive.

Comment: Mein Norddeutsch-gepraegtes Sprachempfinden sagt: Die SMS, die E-Mail, das Flash-Drive, der/das Setup, der Helpdesk, die App.

Answer (score 1):

Wahrscheinlich, weil das im Englischen Neutrum ist. Hat mich schon ein paar mal bei anderen englischen Wörtern irritiert, dass sie in Deutschland von manchen als Neutrum betrachtet werden, obwohl sie im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch maskulin oder feminin sind.

Mein Eindruck ist, dass manche darauf bestehen, dass englische Lehnwörter ihr Genus aus der Originalsprache beibehalten sollten.

Comment: Ausnahmslos jedes einzelne englische Substantiv ist im Original sächlich, weil es im Englischen gar kein anderes Geschlecht für Substantive gibt. Trotzdem sind Wörter wie *die Band, der Brandy, der Chatroom, die CPU, die Domain, der Job, der Hit, die Homepage, der Jackpot, die Lobby, die Party* und hunderte andere nicht sächlich. Die Häufigkeit der drei deutschen Geschlechter ist bei Anglizismen ungefährt gleich groß wie bei urdeutschen Erbwörtern. Ich kann dein Argument daher überhaupt nicht nachvollziehen

Comment: Da es im Englischen keine grammmatikalische Geschlechte gibt, ist kein englisches Substantiv sachlich

Comment: @PiedPiper es gibt aber immer noch die Pronomen, d.h. "he"/"she" für Menschen (manchmal auch für Tiere) und "it" für praktisch alles andere (z.B. "app"). Auch wenn es grammatisch keinen Unterschied mehr macht, gibt es damit doch immer noch einen Rest von Genus, oder nicht?

Comment: Die Applikation ist für mich kein Englisches Lehnwort.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich *Applikation* im Sinne von "Anwendung" (generell) dürfte tatsächlich mit ziemlicher Sicherheit nicht aus dem Englischen kommen. Die Bedeutung "Software", "Programm" aber aber ganz bestimmt

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: In der Bedeutung »Anwendungsprogramm« (also »Computerprogramm für Anwender«) ist *Applikation* sehr wohl aus dem Englischen ins Deutsche gekommen. Das Wort selbst ist natürlich lateinischen Ursprungs, war bis vor wenigen Jahren im Deutschen aber nicht mit der hier diskutierten Bedeutung belegt. Davon abgesehen ist *die Applikation* in allen Bedeutungen ([wovon es rund ein halbes Dutzend gibt](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Applikation)) immer weiblich.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, na eben. Weil *Applikation* weiblich ist, ist für mich folglich auch die Abkürzung *App* weiblich und nicht sächlich.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich, na eben. Genau wie du erwarte ich ja, dass **die** App weiblich ist, und ich habe vor 5 Jahren die Frage gestellt, wie es dazu kommen kann, dass dieses Wort von manchen Menschen in manchen Regionen dem sächlichen Geschlecht zugeordnet wird.

Comment: @JimiJackson Ich habe einen Kommentar von dir gelöscht, weil er unfreundlich ist. Bitte verzichte bei der Beschreibung von Positionen in einer Debatte auf herabwürdigende Begriffe wie "halbgebildete Besserwisser". Ich verstehe, dass Debatten über Sprache mitunter hitzig geführt werden. Dennoch sollten wir versuchen, den Ton zu wahren.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach a) Ich habe schon Computerprofis gehört (Podcast), die explizit mit dem "it" begründet haben, wieso sie im dt. "das" verwenden, obwohl es natürlich keine Regel gibt, das Genus der Ursprungssprache zu übernehmen (le tour de France). Ebenso gibt es keine Regel, das Genus der Übersetzung zu wählen, wie man zig Begriffen sieht, die viele Übersetzungen mit divergierendem Geschlecht haben. Kürzel sind auch nicht auf die Langform rückführbar, siehe "das Modem". b) Würde App "Computerprogramm für Anwender" bedeuten, dann hieße es "Anwenderprogramm", nicht "Anwendungsprogramm".

Answer (score 0):

Ich war auch überrascht, als ich vor ein paar Jahren las, dass "das" auch zulässig ist.

Danach forschte ich ein bisschen nach und kam zu folgendem (nicht-empirischem :) ) Ergebnis:

1. Manchmal hat es mit der Region zu tun.
2. Manchmal ist es eine Frage des persönlichen Geschmacks. (Meine Mutter ist die Einzige in unserer Familie, die "das E-Mail" sagt.)
3. In bekannten Grammatikbüchern wird meistens nur vorsichtig über die unterschiedliche Verwendung des Genus spekuliert.

Hier ist ein interessanter Link für euch:
https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f24a-g/

Der Text im Screenshot ist aus dem Buch "Die Grammatik - Unentbehrlich für richtiges Deutsch"
[image]

Comment: Bitte poste **niemals** Texte als Bilder! Blinde und sehbehinderte Menschen nutzen Vorlese-Software wobei eine Computerstimme den Text vorliest oder Braille-Leser wo der Text auf einem speziellen Gerät in Blindenschrift dargestellt wird. Diese Geräte funktionieren nicht mit Bildern. Daher ersuche ich dich dringend, den Text aus dem Original per Copy&Paste hier einzufügen und das Bild wieder zu löschen.

Answer (score 0):

Zwar habe ich kein Zitat dafür, aber manche neigen dazu, dem englischen Begriff das Geschlecht des deutschen Äquivalents überzustülpen.
Ein Beispiel ist "die File" analog zu "die Datei"
Hier könnte "das Programm" als Vorbild für "das App" gedient haben